# bash script to run various openssl ciphers to decrypt file

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I'm very new to Linux and scripting, but I would like to create a script that runs `openssl` to test various ciphers. I know the password, and I know it was encrypted with `openssl`, but I don't know which cipher was used. I have been attempting this by changing the cipher manually each time, but I thought understanding how a script could do this might be worth figuring out. 
The command I have been using is

```
openssl bf -d -in file.enc -out file.dcrypt
```

this prompts me for the password. 
I have a text file saved with all the ciphers I wish to try with each on a single line.

I want to loop the operation and go through each of the ciphers to see which one works. It would be nice to show the variable as part of the dcrypt file name as well.
is pseudo code

```
start loop n(first line in txt file to eof)
openssl 'n' -d -in file.enc -out file.dcrypt.n (a way to add the password?)
exit eof
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So after playing around with a simple loop I came up with this. It works and I am really amazed at how straight forward the solution was. Not sure if it's the best solution but it works! I can change the output directory for each script I run so my results don’t overwrite each other. Ciphers.txt contains a cipher format per line

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to automate openssl testing
while read p; do

openssl $p -d -in encrypted.txt -out test1234/$p.jpg -pass pass:1234
done <ciphers.txt
```

any comments or critique are appreciated.

Comment: This will go through each line in the file, even if the first one works. You should check the exit status from `openssl` (which will be stored in `$?` after the command is run) and `exit` if it's 0, which indicates success.